# Protocol that supports data integrity with intermittent connectivity?

Tags: mqtt, protocols, lwm2m

Currently we are using LwM2M but we are running into use-cases for which we can't find neat LwM2M features. I also looked at MQTT but it seems to have the same struggles.

These use-cases include:

1. Configuring sensor settings (e.g. temperature interrupt and update
   interval, which are not in the IPSO 3303 object)
2. Not losing sensor readings when they can't be forwarded to the server
   due to bad network coverage, and synchronizing these readings to the
   server after the connection was setup again.
3. Server requesting e.g. last 100 lines of a log. This is too much for
   a single transaction.

Of course we can think of ways to solve these cases, but we are wondering if there are easier ways. Is there another protocol that would maybe better suit our needs?

Comment: Hi Kodiak, your question is not very well stated, and need a lot more info. What device are you using, what server are you using? What LwM2M version can you use? As of today, the latest version of **LwM2M** is **`1.2.1`**, this has support for long sleeping devices with rare wake-ups, however, very few (if not none) of the FOSS servers are supporting this at the moment.